# The Levi-Civita connection in infinite dimensions

Tags: functional-analysis, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

Is there an analogue of the [Fundamental Theorem of Riemannian Geometry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_Riemannian_geometry) for (some subclass of) infinite-dimensional manifolds?

Answer (score 5):

The *Koszul formula* works for the **uniqueness** part of this theorem, but not for the **existence** part in the infinite dimensional case due to the lack of isomorphism between co-tangent and tangent spaces.

With a proper adjustment of definitions one can find analogous facts. See p. 489 **A. Kriegl, P.W. Michor**, The Convenient Setting of Global Analysis, e.g. [here](http://www.mat.univie.ac.at/~michor/apbookh-ams.pdf), and also in **Andrew Stacey**'s notes [here](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/documents/geometry.article.pdf) and [here](http://www.math.ntnu.no/~stacey/Seminars/mathml/noframes/diffloop_nocd.xml#diffloop_nocdse6.xml).